# Are there formatting options for the grails datepicker?

Tags: grails

Can anyone confirm if there are formatting options for the core grails datepicker tag?

My client is requesting that the datepicker uses MM dd yyyy dropdowns instead of the current dd mmmm yyyy dropdowns. I expected it would be an option but surprised to not be able to find it so..

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support formatting. If you require this the [Calendar plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/calendar) is a better option.

Comment: Thanks Don, although I use this also in other projects, this time its the 3 'selects' which is required.. I guess I'll need to look at the tag source and duplicate/modify it slightly to rearrange the order of the html output.